# Webscript create file error

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts

I'm trying to create a file if it doesn't exists or modified it if it exists.

I created a webscript:

> createfile.get.js

```
function main()

{
    var doc = userhome.childByNamePath('answers.txt');
    if (!doc)
    {
        doc = userhome.createFile("answers.txt");
        doc.addAspect("cm:versionable");
        doc.content = 'Questionnaire';

        var trans1 = doc.transformDocument('application/pdf');
    }
    else {
        var workingCopy = doc.checkout();
        workingCopy.content = 'Questionnaire modified';

        // check it in                                                                                
        doc = workingCopy.checkin();
    }
    model.doc=doc;


}

main();
```

However, if I don't have the file in my home, this doesn't create the new file. If I create manually the file "answers.txt" in Alfresco, it modifies the content. Any reason for this?

In catalina.out or in the debugger in the browser, I don't get any information of any error.

Thanks.

Important note: If I don't check if the file exists, and if it exists and if I try to create it with the same code, it says "answers.txt already exists" in catalina.out... So I don't understand, at all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Your code is working good in my machine and I am able to create new file if it doesn't exist.
And I am able to update if exists

please try with `doc.save();`

Comment: I don't  understand. I have a remote machine with an external public IP and I can't create the file. Then, I create a local alfresco in my local machine and I can create the file >.< Damn it. Any advice? I can't get any error.

Comment: Nevermind, I reinstall alfresco and it's done. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about that, but it could be in relation with execute permissions on this script.
Maybe, you can check permissions to execute "createfile.get.js" on remote machine.

Regards,